# Do I need to Allocate Memory for a Dirent Structure

Tags: c, windows, directory, posix

- Platform: Windows XP Service Pack 3
- Compiler: Code::Blocks version 12.11

I am currently writing a program that will recursively delete a given directory using the POSIX directory functions. But I am having a problem with readdir() and its counterpart the dirent structure. I read in readdir's [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/readdir.html) that multiple calls to the function will overwrite the data held in the structure returned by the function. So I thought readdir() must allcoate memmory for the struct itself and then simply reassign the pointer address to the structure that captures it's return value. I tested this theory and I was correct readdir() allocated memmory for it's member d_name. The problem I am having is that readdir returns a NULL pointer when the directory stream is empty, so I use a while loop with the condition (dirent_ptr != NULL) to iterate the entire directory. But because readdir() will handle the memmory allocation of the structure I simply declare a dirent structure and let readdir() do its job. Unfourtatnly for some reason dirent structures are initialized to NULL(or it might be my complier) so my loop never starts because it's conditional statement is not initialy true. So I guess my question is what am I doing wrong here?

Here are important variable declarations and the included librarys. Please note that all of these variables are declared globaly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>

int recursive_delete(const char *path);
int file_delete(const char *path, int file_size);

struct dirent *direntp;
struct stat *statp;

struct switches
{
    int verbose;
    int no_prompt;
    int continue_if_error;
    int files_only;
}; struct switches switches;
```

Rather than resolving relative paths I simply cd to the path given as an argument and then I use the . and .. wildcards to move threw the directorys so that relative paths(d_names) are valid. Also the switches structure simply contains command line switches and should be ignored and I am aware of errors in the following code but unfourtantly I cannot fix them because I cannot get past the above mentioned problem.

```
int recursive_delete(const char *path)
{
    DIR *dirp;
    int return_value = 0;
    int recursive_return_value = 0;

    if((chdir(path)) == -1)
    {
        perror("ERROR(3)");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("CDED to \"%s\"\n", path);

    dirp = opendir(".");
    if(dirp == NULL)
    {
        perror("ERROR(4)");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("OPENED \"%s\"\n", path);

    while(direntp != NULL)
    {
        direntp = readdir(dirp);
        if( (direntp == NULL) && (errno != 0) )
        {
            perror("ERROR(5)");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("READ \"%s\" FROM \"%s\"\n", direntp->d_name, path);

        if( (strcmp(direntp->d_name, ".")!=0) && (strcmp(direntp->d_name, "..")!=0) )
        {
            if((stat(direntp->d_name, statp)) == -1)
            {
                perror("ERROR(6)");
                return 1;
            }
            printf("STATED \"%s\"\n", direntp->d_name);

            if(S_ISREG(statp->st_mode))
            {
                printf("DELETING \"...\\%s\\%s\"\n", path, direntp->d_name);
                return_value += file_delete(direntp->d_name, statp->st_size);
                if( (!switches.continue_if_error) && (return_value != 0) )
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            else if(S_ISDIR(statp->st_mode))
            {
                printf("\n\n\nCALLING RECURSIVE DELETE with \"%s\"\n", direntp->d_name);
                recursive_return_value = recursive_delete(direntp->d_name);
                return_value += recursive_return_value;

                if( (!switches.continue_if_error) && (recursive_return_value != 0) )
                {
                    break;
                }

                if( (!switches.files_only) && (recursive_return_value == 0) )
                {
                    if((chdir("..")) == -1)
                    {
                        perror("ERROR(6)");
                        return 1;
                    }
                    printf("CDED BACK TO \"%s\" FROM \"%s\"\n", path, direntp->d_name);

                    if((rmdir(direntp->d_name)) == -1)
                    {
                        perror("ERROR(7)");
                        return 1;
                    }

                    if(switches.verbose)
                    {
                        printf("DELETED DIRECTORY \"...\\%s\\\"\n\n\n", direntp->d_name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return return_value;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code structure should look something like thhis (with most error checks omitted for clarity):

```
int recursive_delete(const char *path)
{
  DIR* dirp = NULL;
  int return_value = 0;
  char* initial_cur_dir = malloc(1000);

  getcwd(initial_cur_dir, 1000);
  chdir(path);
  dirp = opendir(".");

  while (dirp != NULL)
  {
    struct dirent* direntp;
    struct stat stat;

    direntp = readdir(dirp);

    if (direntp == NULL)
      break;

    stat(direntp->d_name, &stat);

    if (S_ISDIR(statp->st_mode))
    {
      if (strcmp(direntp->d_name, ".") && strcmp(direntp->d_name, ".."))
      {
        return_value += recursive_delete(direntp->d_name);
      }
    }
    else if (S_ISREG(statp->st_mode))
    {
      unlink(direntp->d_name);
    }
  }

  if (initial_cur_dir != NULL)
  {
    chdir(initial_cur_dir);
    rmdir(path);
  }

ErrorLabel: // you should goto here when an error is detected

  if (dirp != NULL)
  {
    closedir(dirp);
  }

  if (initial_cur_dir != NULL)
  {
    chdir(initial_cur_dir);
    free(initial_cur_dir);
  }

  return return_value;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response but I am a little lost as to how this helps me. Declaring direntp every time the loop starts is pointless unless I copy the actual values of the dirent structure to a different structure because readdir() does not use the pointer address of the dirent structure that recieves it's return value. Also I think you miss understood the point of changing the current directory. It is so that relative paths will be valid if I use your above code, rmdir(direntp->d_name) will return a No such file or directory error because recurisive_delete() will change the cwd.

Comment: Did you not see the 2nd `chdir()` at the end??? I prefer to use as few global variables as possible to avoid things like race conditions and to keep relevant code and data close together.

Comment: On a second thought, the above code doesn't delete the specified directory, only everything in it. I'll update it to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

From the code attached, it's not clear where direntp is being initialized (before the `while` loop).  Possibly try something like:

```
direntp = readdir(dirp);
while(direntp != NULL)
{
    // all your work here

    direntp = readdir(dirp);
}
```

This pattern ensures that `direntp` is initialized and updated for your while loop.  However, on second glance of your code I'm not exactly sure what the while loop is supposed to be doing in the first place.  How is `direntp` or `dirp` changing in your loop?

It's possible that you can just get away with an `if` test (instead of the `while`) and just let the recursive call handle the "looping" effect...

Comment: thank for your response and to answer your questions direntp is not initialized it is only globaly declared in the white space before the main function. Which is my question I want to know how it becomes initialized to NULL on its own. Also direntp should hold the file/dir name of the file/dir pointed to by dirp, which should be the current index of the directory stream for the current working directory.

Comment: Oh I almost forgot and yes using an if statment rather than loop would work but that would make stack overflows more likely because the function will be recalled for every single file and sub directory of the orginial argument. recursive_delete() is designed so that it should only recall it's self when it finds a sub directory in the current working directory.

Comment: @JohnVulconshinz Regarding `direntp` initialization: If you're *lucky*, your declarations will be zeroed out (i.e. NULL), however that is usually not guaranteed.  I've seen different behavior on different platforms/environments.  Without an explicit assignment, you could have some trash value initially for your pointer.