# Convert a string Filepath to unique identifier

Tags: c++, c++11

Convert a string  Filepath  to   unique identifier.

This is the kind of filepaths that i need to convert to a unique ID.( int would be preferred)

```
D:\Images\PSSL\2019\Team_Colours\Base_1\Generic.png
D:\Images\Generic.png
D:\Images\Generic\Images\2019\Base.png
```

the path will wary from image to image

Apoligies for not posting any code as i am bit lost on how to proceed

Comment: The process of converting something to an unique ID is generally called *hashing*. That gives you a term to research on. Related: [How to get the MD5 hash of a file in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220046/how-to-get-the-md5-hash-of-a-file-in-c)

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't the path *itself* already a unique identifier? Or are you trying to avoid symlinks? Or do you *actually* mean "integer" when you say "unique identifier".

Comment: warning hashing can produce the same value for different strings

Comment: Nicol i would want to convert  the string to a  unsigned integer value

Comment: Bruno than i believe hashing wont be best solution for that.

Comment: @shomit yes it is available under windows

Comment: @bruno technically true, but with an appropriate hash (e.g. MD5), the chances of a hash collision are small enough that they can typically be ignored.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner a program which have a _small enough_ chance to not work is a program which do not work ^^

Comment: @shomit I edited my answer to add a proposal of class giving unique ID for strings

Comment: You in general cannot convert something to something else that is both unique and smaller than the original something. Perhaps this is an XY problem. Why do you need this?

Comment: @bruno and yet people rely on secure hashing all the time, and the world doesn't end :)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner the OP requests _unique identifier_, by *definition* a _hash_ **cannot** other that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string are not any string but path, if the corresponding files/dir always exist you can use their *node number* (field `d_ino` in `struct dirent`)

Note : *dirent* is available on Linux/Unix/Windows, if you do not have it because of the compiler you use look at [List of all files inside the folder and its subfolders in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54363548/list-of-all-files-inside-the-folder-and-its-subfolders-in-windows)

---

If the file/dir may not exist you can make a dictionary string -> int by yourself, example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <list>

class UI {
  public:
    UI() : next(1) {}
    unsigned search(std::string) const;
    unsigned get(std::string);
    unsigned forget(std::string);

  private:
    std::map<std::string, unsigned> m;
    std::list<unsigned> free;
    unsigned next;
};

unsigned UI::search(std::string s) const {
  std::map<std::string, unsigned>::const_iterator it = m.find(s);

  return (it == m.end()) ? 0 : it->second;
}

unsigned UI::get(std::string s) {
  std::map<std::string, unsigned>::const_iterator it = m.find(s);

  if (it != m.end())
    return it->second;

  unsigned r;

  if (!free.empty()) {
    r = free.front();
    free.pop_front();
  }
  else
    r = next++;

  m[s] = r;
  return r;
}

unsigned UI::forget(std::string s) {
  std::map<std::string, unsigned>::const_iterator it = m.find(s);

  if (it == m.end())
    return 0;

  unsigned r = it->second;

  m.erase(it);

  if (r == (next - 1))
    next -= 1;
  else
    free.push_back(r);

  return r;
}

int main(void)
{
  UI ui;

  std::cout << "aze " << ui.search("aze") << std::endl;  
  std::cout << "aze " <<  ui.get("aze") << std::endl;
  std::cout << "qsd " <<  ui.get("qsd") << std::endl;
  ui.forget("aze");
  std::cout << "aze " << ui.search("aze") << std::endl;
  std::cout << "wxc " <<  ui.get("wxc") << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wall -Wextra c.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
aze 0
aze 1
qsd 2
aze 0
wxc 1
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Notes :

- I do not check if all the possible values of an *unsigned int* are already used when you enter a new string, you will have problem of memory before that case, or use a 64b unsigned to be sure ;-)
- the ID of a string is certainly unique but depends on the historic, a hash do not depends on an historic but several strings may have the same hash

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I do not understand, what do you mean ?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643857/do-i-need-to-allocate-memory-for-a-dirent-structure for instance, or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54363548/list-of-all-files-inside-the-folder-and-its-subfolders-in-windows

Comment: Note that with this approach, the same path-string would correspond to different integer values on different machines (and even on the same machine at different times, e.g. if a file was deleted and then later recreated at the same location).  Also you won't be able to get a node-number for a path that doesn't currently exist.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner yes, this is why I say "_if the corresponding files/dir always exist_" and why I added an other proposal ;-) It is not sure the OP want the same number on different host / executions

Comment: Number can vary on different machines.